# Fancybox giving error: Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'fancybox'

Tags: fancybox

site is http://www.blowingsprings.com/

I have successfully implmented many fancybox structures, but this one has me banging my head against the wall..the error I get is:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

And no matter what I do, it will not work.  jquery is referenced above fancybox, and it is linked correctly from what I can see.  I've also cleared out all other header content and still it wont work.  Any ideas?